# Converting DXL timestamp to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, timestamp, lotus, ibm-doors

totally messed up with Lotus Notes DXL timestamp format...
Given is a timestamp of an exported DXL from a Lotus Notes document, which looks like that:

```
20141104T132939,49+01
```

Trying to get the format working with `DateTime.ParseExact`, like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr.Substring(0, 13), "yyyyMMddThhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
```

But with no luck >>> `System.FormatException "no valid DateTime format"`.

Can C# handle the above timestamp as it is?

Comment: The first part seems simple - you should quote the `T`, the `hh` should be `HH`, and ideally you should include the seconds as well... but do you know what the `,49+01` is meant to indicate?

Comment: Right, don't know what to do with the part behind the comma ... The seconds are not really needed in the current app case, but would be nice to have, also. :) Do I really need to SubString first? Debugging shows me, that the SubString cut seems no to be done, but it is working ...

Comment: Quoting helps, and the Exception is gone, by also changing the "hh" to "HH". So if you place this as answer, i will set this question answered. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your text format - you've used `hh` which is the *12-hour* clock, but you've got a value of 13. You want `HH`, which is the 24-hour clock. I'd also recommend quoting the `T` as you just want the literal `T` character, and also taking the following two characters for the second:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateStr.Substring(0, 15),
    "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I would then suggest keeping it as a `DateTime` for as long as you can, only converting back to a string where you actually need to display this to a client.